# How to extend javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have 2 BI object in different files, now I want to extend the first object with other ones.

1st Object

```
var BI = BI || {};
BI = {
    firstInit: function () {
        console.log('I am first init');
    }
}
```

Other file

2nd Object

```
BI = {
   init: function () {
     console.log('I am init');
   }
}
```

Now I want 2nd Object should contain the `firstInit` as well. Let me know I can explain further. I am using jQuery.

Comment: Use `extend` method : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: @Cherniv that deserves to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: If you can edit the other file then just use: `BI.init = function () {
    console.log('I am init');
}`

Comment: jQuery is not needed, JavaScript functions are great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) here.

Try following code

```
var BI = BI || {};
BI = {
  firstInit: function () {
    console.log('I am first init');
  }
}

$.extend(BI, {
  init: function () {
    console.log('I am init');
  }
});

console.log(BI);
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcZjJ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, you can't do it that easily with good x-browser support.

However, jQuery does give you a means to have objects extend eachother: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

So you would do:

```
var extended = $.extend({}, BI, {
   init: function () {
     console.log('I am init');
   }
});
```

The first argument (empty object, `{}`) means that the properties of `BI` (the second argument) and the object you pass in will be combined in to the new object.

I wrote a small polymorphic extension to `$.extend` for this purpose which will allow you to extend from multiple objects, with the latter item taking precidence:

```
mergeObjects = function () {
  // Convert the arguments Array-like object to an actual array
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  // Only one item? If we give this to $.extend it'll extend jQuery, which is
  // not the desired result, so let's spit it back verbatim
  if (args.length === 1) {
    return args[0];
  }

  // We need to make sure we're always combining objects starting with a
  // completely empty one
  args.unshift(true, {});
  return jQuery.extend.apply(jQuery, args);
};
```

So, you can define your base module with common properties like so:

```
var MyBaseModule.prototype = {
  options: {},
  getOptions: function () {
    return this.options || {};
  },
  setOptions: function (options) {
    this.options = options;
  },
  log: function () {
    // do your logging stuff here
  },
  error: function () {
    // do your error handling stuff here
  }
};
```

And your actual modules:

```
var MyModule = function () {
  // constructor code here
};

var MyModule.prototype = mergeObjects(MyBaseModule, {
  // define your module's methods here
});
```

...now MyModule has "inherited" the `options` property and options getter and setter. You can instantiate the new module with `new MyModule`;

If you want a vanilla way of doing it, [this post](http://uxebu.com/blog/2011/02/23/object-based-inheritance-for-ecmascript-5/) may be useful

Comment: Note that this will create a new object with the properties copied into it rather than extending the first object.

Comment: If you can do it with jQ, you can do it _out of the box_, too. There's nothing jQ does, you can't do with VanillaJS

Comment: Sure, ECMA5 makes it easier, but there's no quick and easy without rolling your own

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Cool, can you share any example without using jQuery I would love to know that. However I ll google anyways.. Thanks

Comment: @illumine: `function cloneO(o){ function F(){}; F.prototype = o; return new F;}` uses an object as the prototype of a new object, then add the methods/properties you want to extend the original object with, to the clone. That's all.

Comment: *"Out of the box, you can't do it that easily with good x-browser support."* Iterating over the properties of an object with a `for` loop doesn't seem to be very difficult to me.

Comment: @illumine: Added a vanillaJS function that clones/extends, that can be written in a mere 5 lines of code... it's really not that hard

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this in JavaScript. One is using prototype chaining, the other is to just copy the method. In this case both of your objects have the object as the prototype, so you need to copy the method:

```
BI2.init = BI1.firstInit;
```

To copy all methods and attributes in JQuery, use $.extend;

```
BI2 = $.extend({ init: function () { } }, BI1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript Functions are objects. So they can be passed as arguments to functions or assigned to other variables (referenced).

```
var BI = {
    firstInit: function () {
        console.log('I am first init');
    }
};

var BI2 = {
   init: function () {
     console.log('I am init');
   }
}

// copy the reference of function
BI2.originalFirstInit = BI.firstInit;

// run this function
BI2.originalFirstInit(); // output: "I am first init"
```